# Can you create polyfills in swift using availability checking?

Tags: swift

Swift 2 lets you check the current platform and version to make sure that newer methods/properties are available and allow you to write fallback code if they are not, by writing a conditional block with `#available`.

So for example, in OSX10.10, `NSTextField` has a property called `placeholderString`, but in older versions, you had to access this info via an intermediate `NSTextFieldCell` object.  You could safely use the new system with a fallback for the old one like this:

```
var placeholder : String
if #available(OSX 10.10, *) {
    placeholder = inputBox.placeholderString!
} else {
    placeholder = (inputBox.cell as! NSTextFieldCell).placeholderString!
}
```

Swift also allows you to extend existing classes with `extension`

For example, adding the placeholder property to `NSTextField`

```
extension NSTextField {
    var placeholderString: String? {
        return (self.cell as! NSTextFieldCell).placeholderString
    }
}
```

So...  Is it possible to combine these 2 ideas and create something like a polyfill, where we extend a class conditionally on the current platform, in order to retrospectively add features of the new API to older platforms?

So in my example, I would want to write something like this:

```
if !#available(OSX 10.10, *) {
    extension NSTextField {
        var placeholderString: String? {
            return (self.cell as! NSTextFieldCell).placeholderString
        }
    }
}
```

The above doesn't compile.  But it illustrates the kind of thing I'm looking for.  If a particular thing is available on the current platform, then use it, otherwise supply an implementation for it.

Is there any way in Swift to achieve this?

Subsequently you would be able to safely use `textField.placeholderString` without needing to worry about the platform version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if #available()` is checked a *runtime*, not at compile or link time.
Therefore I assume that the only possible way is to define a wrapper
method:

```
extension NSTextField {
    var myPlaceholderString: String? {
        if #available(OSX 10.10, *) {
            return self.placeholderString
        } else {
            return (self.cell as! NSTextFieldCell).placeholderString
        }
    }
}
```

(and I understand that this is not exactly what you are looking for.)
Perhaps someone else has a better solution!

Comment: That looks like a pretty decent solution - clean, safe and neat. Thanks.  Shame there isn't any way to keep the old name.  Unless someone else has another idea?